# How to make a html-5 banner with 100% height?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a banner with fixed width(300 px), but adaptive height ( minimum height should stay 600 px). I created my banner in Adobe Animate and this code was generted but this function changes both height and width and doesn't make height bigger, than 600 px.
Help me please change this function

```
    function makeResponsive(isResp, respDim, isScale, scaleType) {      
    var lastW, lastH, lastS=1;      
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);        
    resizeCanvas();     
    function resizeCanvas() {           
        var w = lib.properties.width, h = lib.properties.height;            
        var iw = window.innerWidth, ih=window.innerHeight;          
        var pRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1, xRatio=iw/w, yRatio=ih/h, sRatio=1;          
        if(isResp) {                
            if((respDim=='width'&&lastW==iw) || (respDim=='height'&&lastH==ih)) {                    
                sRatio = lastS;                
            }               
            else if(!isScale) {                 
                if(iw<w || ih<h)                        
                    sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);              
            }               
            else if(scaleType==1) {                 
                sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);              
            }               
            else if(scaleType==2) {                 
                sRatio = Math.max(xRatio, yRatio);              
            }           
        }           
        canvas.width = w*pRatio*sRatio;         
        canvas.height = h*pRatio*sRatio;
        canvas.style.width = dom_overlay_container.style.width = anim_container.style.width =  w*sRatio+'px';               
        canvas.style.height = anim_container.style.height = dom_overlay_container.style.height = h*sRatio+'px';
        stage.scaleX = pRatio*sRatio;           
        stage.scaleY = pRatio*sRatio;           
        lastW = iw; lastH = ih; lastS = sRatio;            
        stage.tickOnUpdate = false;            
        stage.update();            
        stage.tickOnUpdate = true;      
    }
}
makeResponsive(true,'height',false,2);  
AdobeAn.compositionLoaded(lib.properties.id);
fnStartAnimation();
```

}

Comment: You could do this with CSS only.  Just set width="300px", min-height="600px".  I'm not sure _how_ you want to make it adaptive.

Comment: this function was generated by Adobe Animate in which I cheked the boxes  "Make responsive" only height.
but it changes also the width

Comment: I don't know how Adobe Animate works, and if you don't find an answer for this with JavaScript, I would recommend using CSS.

Comment: What is the expected outcome? Width is fixed at 300px but height is minimum 600px?

Comment: yes, minimum height of this banner should stay 600 px but height should can be scaling

Comment: Hmm, but if you do that, the content of your banner will be stretched as they are not scaled proportionately, unless that is already handled inside your banner?

Comment: it scaled proportionately. i just don't know how to scale it ONLY by height

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Please try this instead. This code resizes the canvas height only and doesn't touch the stage.

```
function resizeCanvas() {         
    var w = lib.properties.width, h = lib.properties.height;            
    var iw = window.innerWidth, ih=window.innerHeight;          
    var pRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1, xRatio=iw/w, yRatio=ih/h, sRatio=1;          
    if(isResp) {          
        // added these 4 lines     
        if(yRatio>1)
            sRatio = yRatio;
        else
            sRatio = 1;

        // commented this out
        // if((respDim=='width'&&lastW==iw) || (respDim=='height'&&lastH==ih)) {                    
        //  sRatio = lastS;                
        // }                
        // else if(!isScale) {                  
        //  if(iw<w || ih<h)                        
        //      sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);              
        // }                
        // else if(scaleType==1) {                  
        //  sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);              
        // }                
        // else if(scaleType==2) {                  
        //  sRatio = Math.max(xRatio, yRatio);              
        // }            
    }           

        // canvas.width = w*pRatio*sRatio;          
        canvas.height = h*pRatio*sRatio;
        // canvas.style.width = dom_overlay_container.style.width = anim_container.style.width =  w*sRatio+'px';                
        canvas.style.height = anim_container.style.height = dom_overlay_container.style.height = h*sRatio+'px';
        // stage.scaleX = pRatio*sRatio;            
        // stage.scaleY = pRatio*sRatio;            
        lastW = iw; lastH = ih; lastS = sRatio;            
        stage.tickOnUpdate = false;            
        stage.update();            
        stage.tickOnUpdate = true;      
}
```

This chunk of code is the same as what is published by Animate except:

- Added the 4 lines
- Commented out the IF block
- Commented out canvas.width and stage scaling

**OLD ANSWER BELOW**

Ok, thanks for the info. Try this. I updated "resizeCanvas()" function:

```
function resizeCanvas() {           
        var w = lib.properties.width, h = lib.properties.height;            
        var iw = window.innerWidth, ih=window.innerHeight;          
        var pRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1, xRatio=iw/w, yRatio=ih/h, sRatio=1;          
        if(isResp) {          
            // added these 4 lines     
            if(yRatio>1)
                sRatio = yRatio;
            else
                sRatio = 1;

            // commented this out
            // if((respDim=='width'&&lastW==iw) || (respDim=='height'&&lastH==ih)) {                    
            //  sRatio = lastS;                
            // }                
            // else if(!isScale) {                  
            //  if(iw<w || ih<h)                        
            //      sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);              
            // }                
            // else if(scaleType==1) {                  
            //  sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);              
            // }                
            // else if(scaleType==2) {                  
            //  sRatio = Math.max(xRatio, yRatio);              
            // }            
        }           

        // canvas.width = w*pRatio*sRatio;          -- commented this out
        canvas.width = w*pRatio;                    // replaced with this
        canvas.height = h*pRatio*sRatio;
        // canvas.style.width = dom_overlay_container.style.width = anim_container.style.width =  w*sRatio+'px';            -- commented this out
        canvas.style.width = dom_overlay_container.style.width = anim_container.style.width =  w+'px';                      // replaced with this
        canvas.style.height = anim_container.style.height = dom_overlay_container.style.height = h*sRatio+'px';
        // stage.scaleX = pRatio*sRatio;        -- commented this out
        stage.scaleX = pRatio;                  // replaced with this
        stage.scaleY = pRatio*sRatio;           
        lastW = iw; lastH = ih; lastS = sRatio;            
        stage.tickOnUpdate = false;            
        stage.update();            
        stage.tickOnUpdate = true;      
    }
```

I did a few things here:

- Only scale if yRatio (height) is more than 1, otherwise default scale ratio(sRatio) to 1.
- Disable scaling on width

Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much!You helped me a lot, but now the content of the banner is stretched to the height, and I need the content remained in the center and the space from the top and bottom of the banner filled with a background

Comment: Ah, so this means the banner itself should not scale? My understanding of your original question is so that the "minimum height of this banner should stay 600 px but height should can be scaling". Can you help me understand it better? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to always center the banner to the browser but the banner dimension itself is fixed at 300x600?

Comment: only width(300) is fixed. height should be 100%,scaling, but only canvas with background,not the content.

Comment: updated the answer. Not sure if this is what you are looking for.